# how to create setup file for windows phone mobile?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I created an application for windows phone, how to install it on mobile device? application created in c#, with visual studio SDK, it can work on emulator

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy it to device from visual studio, or using XapDeployer.exe from SDK.

[How to: Build and Deploy a Windows Phone Application Using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928362%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Don't forget to register you device as a developer's one.

If you need to give your app to other users you have to [upload it to the Marketplace](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-7-app-marketplace).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your device is unlocked (in other words you signed up and paid in App Hub) you can use both Visual Studio and App Deployment tool described ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)).

Cheers,